# Cannot access Odoo Studio after "messed up" in properties / widget

Tags: odoo

In Odoo studio, I "played" around in the widget where there is a selection of data type such as "float".

I mistakenly changed the type from "float" to something else.

Which now I cannot access into Odoo Studio to changed back the setting

I would like to know how to resolve this error

Thanks a lot!

Odoo 14.0+e (Enterprise Edition)

Error as follows

Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digits')
at Class._render (https://mycompany.odoo.com/stock/static/src/js/forecast_widget.js:34:124)
at https://mycompany.odoo.com/web/static/src/js/fields/abstract_field.js:209:25

Answer (score 2):

To change it back you can open the view which you modified in studio for example if you modified sale order form, open any sale order in form view and `enable developer` mode and then from `debug icon` select `Edit view: Form`, the form view will be shown go to `inherited views` tab and you will find many views but you will find view with name start with `Odoo Studio` click on it and then the the inherited view will be opened and from `Architecture` tab you will see the xml code so you will look into it and comment the widget change using `<!-- -->` or delete it.

You can check this [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/saISZQcyGAU)

Comment: This is good explanation and i would like to add small details : Odoo Studio works by overriding previous record to the latest ones. For example, if the view has a string and you edit that string to be bold, `Odoo Studio` will write a new XPath code that later will refer to that string inside Odoo Studio inherit file. If you wish to revert back several changes, you need to open that Odoo Studio inherited files, scroll down, and comment it as @Waleed Mohsen explain.